# How can I restore a wordpress website from a copied directory?

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a domain on a website that offered also the wordpress editor. I did a first sketch using the `/wp` subdomain and then I tried to move it to the root but I failed and messed up the wordpress settings..

I changed the Wordpress Address

[image]

from `www.biancodichina.com/wp` to `www.biancodichina.com/` without copying the content of my `/public/www/wp` to `/public/www`

Result? Website unreachable of course...

But since I had a backup of my `/public/www/wp` [image]

I reinstalled wordpress from zero as it was at begin, basically.

Now I copied back my backup overwriting the content of the `/wp` directory to `/public/www/wp` (except the `wp-config.php`), but I dont see the contents, I recognize some writtens, but the contents are missing, I guess because I should have also backup the database or what?

Comment: I'm not sure what you did exactly, but this shows how to show a sub-directory install as you root site: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install

Comment: To sum up, I have only that folder as backup, no database backup, what can I restore with that? Btw, thanks for the link!

Comment: Just moving and replacing that folder won't have deleted the database, but it's difficult to tell exactly what you've done.  Try logging into MySQL on the host (using PhpMyAdmin or however you do it) and resetting the 'siteurl' and 'home' entries in the `wp_options` table to the URLs they were before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take db backup first and then export db.
2. On sql file find `www.biancodichina.com/wp` and replace with `www.biancodichina.com`, then save sql file.
3. After that import sql file and check website.